# Can I change syslog or syslog-ng log level at runtime?

Tags: logging, syslog, syslog-ng

Sometimes, there are too many log messages and I have no control over them all. If I can set the log level at runtime, it would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

if your syslog-ng is not too old, you can enable debug/verbose messages using syslog-ng-ctl: https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/syslog-ng-ctl.1.html

But it's probably more convenient if you are running syslog-ng in the foreground (syslog-ng -F).

Regards,

Robert